# Why spring boot actuator shows aggregate results of all properties under "bootstrapProperties"?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

We have spring boot (2.0.3) version of app deployed in production PCF. Recently we noticed that when we check the "/actuator/env" endpoint of the app, it shows aggregate results of all properties under single node called "bootstrapProperties".

What we instead expect is that endpoint "/actuator/env" should show that which property was resolved from which file.

How can we fix this issue?

Note: We have some apps with same version which is showing the correct results.

Comment: do all the apps have spring-cloud?

Comment: Yes, all apps have those deps defined. Weired thing is that in lower envt same app and version give correct output in /actuator/env vs other envt where it shows aggregate results.